# postfix handoff to dovecot, status=bounced (user unknown)

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am going through the process of setting up a mailserver.  I've written e-commerce, OOP, JS goodies etc. and this is the most difficult and comprehensive trial I've gone through so far.

I have set postfix to use virtual domains and users via a mysql database.  I know this is working that far because when I deliberately change the email address in the Users table of the database, I get the first message shown below.  Once I correct it I get the second.

why am I getting the following (highlighted) line?:

```
-- with incorrect database entry --

Jul  4 18:24:38 mailer postfix/smtpd[5109]: connect from unknown[67.205.1.1]
Jul  4 18:24:38 mailer postfix/smtpd[5109]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[67.205.1.1]: 550 5.1.1 <homeboyjohn@gobycompass.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<root@tothebatcave.com> to=<homeboyjohn@gobycompass.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<tothebatcave.com>
Jul  4 18:24:38 mailer postfix/smtpd[5109]: disconnect from unknown[67.205.1.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=4/6

-- with database entry changed back --
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/smtpd[5109]: connect from unknown[67.205.1.1]
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/smtpd[5109]: 593F517B342: client=unknown[67.205.1.1]
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/cleanup[5116]: 593F517B342: message-id=<20190704182522.13B05A2400@tothebatcave.com>
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/qmgr[5082]: 593F517B342: from=<root@tothebatcave.com>, size=542, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/smtpd[5109]: disconnect from unknown[67.205.1.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
#### -- here is where dovecot seems to be missing something --
#### -- (either from the handoff, or configuration?  I don't know..) --
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/pipe[5117]: 593F517B342: to=<homeboyjohn@gobycompass.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown)
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/cleanup[5116]: 642E017B348: message-id=<20190704182522.642E017B348@mailer.compasspoint-servicehost.com>
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/bounce[5120]: 593F517B342: sender non-delivery notification: 642E017B348
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/qmgr[5082]: 642E017B348: from=<>, size=2627, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/qmgr[5082]: 593F517B342: removed
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/smtp[5121]: 642E017B348: to=<root@tothebatcave.com>, relay=tothebatcave.com[67.205.1.1]:25, delay=0.07, delays=0/0.01/0.05/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 73FF7A23F1)
Jul  4 18:25:22 mailer postfix/qmgr[5082]: 642E017B348: removed
```

To keep things simple, I'm attaching the settings from `conf.d/10-mail.cf` (a lot of these posts are really long).  Will attach more if requested, thanks!

```
mail_home = /var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
# mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/www/%d/mail/%u
mail_location = maildir:~
```

Comment: Please add to your question the changes you made to `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext` and also any configuration files that it references.

Comment: Michael, thanks for this lead!  There are actually no changes I have made in that file.  Since your post I've looked at https://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL - the thing is that I've already got usernames and passwords in a db `EmailServer_db.Users_tbl`.  The passwords are also hashed with a `$6$` on the front etc.  Appreciate further assistance.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't finished setting up Dovecot. Go back to whatever tutorial you were following and complete it.